# Using jquery Virtual Keyboard with CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, virtual-keyboard

Has anyone figured out how to use Mottie's Virtual Keyboard (http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/) with CKEditor?  The Virtual Keyboard is designed to be used with input and text area fields but CKEditor turns the text area into an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor actually creates a contenteditable div.

Sadly, the virtual keyboard does not currently work with contenteditable elements, only inputs & textareas. I do plan on adding support for it, but my time is limited so any assistance with coding would be greatly appreciated.

There is an [example of making the keyboard work with Codemirror](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/issues/306).